# How to make a sql query faster with parameter?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2014

I have two date parameters in my query and it runs around 7 mins but if I remove parameters and use the set values in the where clause then it runs 3 mins.

Let's say: 
Query 1.

```
declare @parameter1 date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),
        @parameter2 date=GETDATE()
Select 
...
where date between @parameter1 and @parameter2
```

Query 2.

```
Select 
...
where date between date1 and date2
```

Why first query runs slower than the second? How can I improve the performance? I have to have parameters in my report as I'm building SSRS report.

Comment: This is often something called "parameter sniffing". Try putting `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` right at the end and see if it fixes it

Comment: Using profiler see execution plans of two queries